# Solving an equation with variable in exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

can anyone please assist in solving the following equation for $t$? I am having trouble once since I have some $t$ terms which are in the exponent and some which are not...

$$0.6e^{-\dfrac{t}{20}}(1-\dfrac{t}{20})+0.5e^{\dfrac{-30+t}{10}}(-1+\dfrac{30-t}{10})=0  $$

Expanding didn't seem to help at all, but I'm not sure how to factor this more to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that your equation can factorized into
$-{\frac { \left( t-20 \right)  \left( 3\,{{\rm e}^{-t/20}}+5\,{{\rm e}
^{-3+t/10}} \right) }{100}}=0
$
does this help you?